# Android Animation - Substitute ImageViews for other element in a GridView

Tags: android, animation, gridview, textview, imageview

I have a GridView with ImageView in each position.
I want to put an animation to feel like each ImageView is a flipcard. But in the verse of each "card", I wanna to show some text information. So, the question is:

How to apply an animation in each ImageView of the Grid to substitute it for a TextView? And to the the reverse, to substitute the TextView for a ImageView?
How to do it (as shown in the example above)? Thanks a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library should do the job for you. 
[CardFlipAnimation Library](https://github.com/balesz/android-tutorial-CardFlipAnimation)

Comment: My doubt is not about this animation specifically, but how to apply the animation to substitute one kind of view to another, in a gridview. But thanks. :-)

Comment: It flips the view and shows a different layout. Try its sample apk.

Comment: I did not find the sample apk. I tried to import into a project in Eclipse and didn't work, too...

Comment: Goto the Play store > download Libraries for developers > navigate to Animations > CardFlipAnimation.

Comment: It is really a good tip! This apk shows examples of many libraries! This set of links may help me in others parts of my work. I would like to know how to do it without lib, but now I'll try to learn how to use this library, if you are saying it provides animation between different layouts (visually I can not see this, just a flipcard animation, but if you are saying it, I'll try to use it).  Thanks!